# search members with certain naming pattern in a structure in c

Tags: c, search, find, pattern-matching, structure

I need to find structure members and size from a structure having certain naming pattern.

for EX :

```
struct  my_struct
{
    uint8_t MOD_reserved0[4];

    struct {
         uint32_t  member1:8;                    
         uint32_t  member2:24;                  
    } sub_structure1;

    uint8_t MOD_reserved1[20];

    struct {
         uint32_t  member1:8;                    
         uint32_t  member2:24;                  
    } sub_structure2;

    uint8_t MOD_reserved2[64];
}
```

now I need to find all   **MOD_reservedXX[]**  members and their size.

XX  will be as 0,1,2,3,4,.... n as following

Address of MOD_reserved0  and size - 4

Address of MOD_reserved1  and size - 20

Address of MOD_reserved2  and size - 64

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you asking?  It seems like you already answered your own question.  Did you want a programmatic way to do it?  Can you give an example of how you want to use this info in your code?

Comment: do you want `offsetof` ?

Comment: Hi , I have some structures  inside which some reserved spaces are there. (MOD_reserved0 , MOD_reserved1 etc ). I want to get the reserved places start address and size, 

Basically it is from a chip header file where  my_struct represents a MODULE (ex- I2C) register structures and sub_structure1/2 are the 32Bit registers in it. There are some reserved address in between. . am trying to get the reserved address start address and their length from the header file . Reserved address variable names are in certain pattern as shown above.

Please reply if I am unclear in the question